# Laravel 5 extend auth::user() with information from other database table

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I am using `Auth::user()` to get information on the current logged in user. Now I want to extend the Information delivered by `Auth::user()`. Concrete the *activation state* of the user shall be available.

This information is stored in the table *activations* in the column *state*.

From my understanding `Auth::user()` delivers what will be retrived from the *user model*. So I should create a relationship between table *users* and table *activations*. The [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#one-to-one) states 2 posibilites, both require that the *activations* table has a foreign_key *user_id*.

My table layout does not cover that, I just have refernce in the *users* table to the *actvtion_id*.

is there a possibilty to build a relationsship with my table layout, which leads to the desired result, that `Auth::user()` deliveres me the *activation state*? If how should I do it?

Or do I have to switch the table layout as recommended in the documentation?

Below my table code:

**Controller**:

```php
class ProfileController extends Controller {

    public function me()
    {
        return Auth::user(  );
    }
}
```

**users (migration)**:

```php
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->integer('activation_id')->unsigned(); 
        $table->foreign('activation_id')->references( 'id' )->on( 'activations' );
        //...
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**activations (migration)**:

```php
    Schema::create('activations', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');   
        $table->string('activationStatus', 1)->nullable()->default('N');
        // ...
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to define a model relationship in your User model:

```
public function activation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Activations', 'activation_id');
}
```

Now, you can easily lazy load the Activation relationship from the authenticated user:

```
$user = Auth::user()->load('activation');
```

If you want to get the activation status, you can now do:

```
var_dump($user->activation->activationStatus); // Prints 'Y' / 'N'
```

Comment: Worked. I had to add `use App\Activation` to the User model. And `return $this->belongsTo('App\Activation', 'activation_id');` Activation without *s*.